# which form of encryption is used in this asp function

Tags: encryption, vbscript, scripting, asp-classic

Below asp function is used to encrypt passwords.

```
Function EncryptPassword(vPwd)
    vTempPwd = ""
    EncryptPassword = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(vPwd)
        vTempPwd = vTempPwd & Chr((255 - Asc(Mid(vPwd, i, i))) / 2)
    Next
    For i = Len(vPwd) + 1 To 10
        vTempPwd = vTempPwd & CStr(i - Len(vPwd))
    Next
    EncryptPassword = vTempPwd
End Function
```

Can anyone just tell me which method of encryption is this? I want to use the same method of encryption is asp.net.

Comment: That's not [encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) more obfuscation. I wouldn't recommend using it in any web application. Ideally if moving to .Net you should be using a well established Cryptographic Provider in the [`System.Security.Cryptography`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) namespace.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't `...Asc(Mid(vPwd, i, 1)))...`?

Comment: You shouldn't encrypt passwords, you should be doing a one way hash (with a salt) with passwords.  Encrypted payloads can be decrypted (if you obtain the keys).   See Cryptographic hash function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

Comment: As @Dijkgraaf there is no need for you to encrypt a users password in fact you shouldn't even know about it, storing the slated hash of the users password is more then enough. Having said that this method is plain character substitution nothing more and wouldn't recommend this type of code in any application. If you want a little more information [great blog article this morning by Troy Hunt](https://www.troyhunt.com/security-insanity-how-we-keep-failing-at-the-basics/) about this topic *(see the section "Crazy password advice (and censoring critics")*.

Comment: Also excellent advice here - [Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)