# decrypt (decipher) function for this encryption (cipher)

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

```
Function EncryptPassword(vPwd)
  vTempPwd = ""
  EncryptPassword = ""
  For i = 1 To Len(vPwd)
    vTempPwd = vTempPwd & Chr((255 - Asc(Mid(vPwd, i, i))) / 2)
  Next
  For i = Len(vPwd) + 1 To 10
    vTempPwd = vTempPwd & CStr(i - Len(vPwd))
  Next
  EncryptPassword = vTempPwd 
End Function
```

I have been asked to write a <strike>decrypt</strike> decipher function for the above <strike>encryption</strike> cipher. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Did you chose to ignore the advice you were given a few days ago? - dup of [which form of encryption is used in this asp function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38127127/692942). I said it then and I'll say it now that isn't encryption at best it's character substitution a form of obfuscation and easily breakable. You shouldn't be using this in **any** web application.

Comment: @Lankymart: my boss asks me to do stupid stuff all the time. Sometimes, I can talk him off the ledge; other times, I just have to swallow my pride and do it his way - it's his company, not mine. If you're not in the same boat, count your blessings, but lay off of those of us who aren't so lucky.

Comment: @Martha being asked to do stupid stuff is one thing, being asked to do dangerous stuff that the company could end up being liable for is quite another. If they are using this as a poor mans encryption to encrypt user passwords, what is it securing? Customer details, payment information etc...Just don't do it and explain to your boss why. Besides this is an internet community where the questions / answers benefit more then just the OP, so I'd rather not have people thinking this is encryption when it clearly isn't.

Comment: @Martha my boss still expects me to work on Classic ASP, never do I consider myself lucky.

Comment: There are a lot of collisions (characters being encoded to the same character) in that EncryptPassword fuction, so you could write a function to give you a string that would "encrypt" to the same EncryptPassword, you cannot say for certain that you have the original vPwd

Comment: For example both "password1234" and "parrword1234" end up as HOFFDHFNgfff and that is with changing only one character to it's collision character (and every character has a collision character in this function)

Answer (score 1):

The following function will give you a string password back that will if passed to the EncryptPassword function end up with the same cipher string as the original password.

```
Function DecryptPassword(vPwd)
  vTempPwd = ""
  DecryptPassword = ""
  For i = 1 To Len(vPwd)
    vTempPwd = vTempPwd & Chr((255 - Asc(Mid(vPwd, i, 1)) * 2))
  Next
  DecryptPassword = vTempPwd 
End Function
```

Note: It will not necessarily give you back exactly the same string as the original password as each character has at least one "collision" character, that is that they will cipher to the same value.  Also the EncryptPassword function will pad it out to at least 10 characters so if your original password is shorter, you will end up with a 10 character string that ciphers to the same string.

Below is the full script I tested with running a .vbs file using cscript

```
pw1 = "password1234"
pwC1 = EncryptPassword(pw1)

pw2 = DecryptPassword(pwC1)
pwC2 = EncryptPassword(pw2)

If pwC1 = pwC2 Then
  WScript.Echo  pw1 & " and " & pw2 & " cipher to the same value off " & pwC1 
else
  WScript.Echo pw1 & " chipher is " & pwC1 & " and " & pw2 & " cipher is " & pwC2
End If

Function EncryptPassword(vPwd)
  vTempPwd = ""
  EncryptPassword = ""
  For i = 1 To Len(vPwd)
    vTempPwd = vTempPwd & Chr((255 - Asc(Mid(vPwd, i, i))) / 2)
  Next
  For i = Len(vPwd) + 1 To 10
    vTempPwd = vTempPwd & CStr(i - Len(vPwd))
  Next
  EncryptPassword = vTempPwd 
End Function

Function DecryptPassword(vPwd)
  vTempPwd = ""
  DecryptPassword = ""
  For i = 1 To Len(vPwd)
    vTempPwd = vTempPwd & Chr((255 - Asc(Mid(vPwd, i, 1)) * 2))
  Next
  DecryptPassword = vTempPwd 
End Function
```

Note: As was said in the notes of the comments of the original question `Asc(Mid(vPwd, i, i))` can also be `Asc(Mid(vPwd, i, 1))` as the Asc function only parses the first character anyway.